# adding custom user input fields in WordPress admin dashboard gives error The link you followed has expired. Please try again

Tags: php, theme-development, themes, user-meta, php.ini

I am developing a wordpress theme for themeforest so its for commercial use and adding a custom input field of social media to the user menu in the WordPress dashboard gives error after i click Update Profile. The front-end appears correctly but when i submit it by clicking Update Profile button it takes me to a next page where it says

> The link you followed has expired.Please try again.

it works when i remove my custom input fields.
Following are its screenshots

[image: Wordpress Dashboard user menu with custom fields of social]

[image: Error Thrown when i submit the user profile with my custom fields]

Following is my code (written in a extra-user-fields.php file which i include in functions.php):

```
<?php

add_action( 'show_user_profile', '_themename_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', '_themename_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action('user_new_form', '_themename_extra_user_profile_fields');

function _themename_extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3><?php _e("Extra profile information", "_themename"); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">

    <?php wp_nonce_field( '_themename_user_extra_fields_verify' ); ?>

    <tr>
        <th><label for="facebook"><?php _e("Facebook Profile Link","_themename"); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="facebook" id="facebook" value="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_author_meta( 'facebook', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text"/><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e("Please enter your facebook profile link."); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="twitter"><?php _e("Twitter Profile Link","_themename"); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="twitter" id="twitter" value="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text"/><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e("Please enter your twitter profile link."); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<?php }

    function _themename_save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) {
            wp_die( __( 'You are not allowed to be on this page.', '_themename' ) );
        }
        check_admin_referer( '_themename_user_extra_fields_verify' );

        $escaped_facebook_url   = esc_url($_POST['facebook']);
        $escaped_twitter_url    = esc_url($_POST['twitter']);
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'facebook', $escaped_facebook_url);
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'twitter', $escaped_twitter_url);
    }
    
    add_action( 'personal_options_update', '_themename_save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', '_themename_save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
    add_action('user_register', '_themename_save_extra_user_profile_fields');
?>
```

The error only gets removed when i completely remove the _themename_save_extra_user_profile_fields() function and its add_action and completely empties the _themename_extra_user_profile_fields() function too.

Also i researched online and to fix this error i need to increase the limit size of uploading of WordPress through htaccess file etc. **But as i said i am making a theme for themeforest so it will be for commercial use and i can't just fix this error here and then ask users of my theme to do the same to change the limit size of uploading etc.** so that fix doesn't work for me

Comment: Thank you it worked. i didn't know that that the form itself has a nonce which obviously it should have. anyhow thank you very much i got my answer. please write an answer to this question so it could be marked as a proper answer

Comment: Note that you incorrectly placed the `wp_nonce_field()` call - (and although you no longer use it,) it should've been placed outside the `<table>`. And for saving an URL to the database, you wouldn't use `esc_url()`; instead, you can use `esc_url_raw()` or `sanitize_text_field()`.

Comment: yeah i forgot about the esc_url_raw() thanks for the note and info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error messages means a failed admin nonce validation (check_admin_referer, which calls wp_nonce_ays). And you don't actually need an extra nonce here: these are extra fields to be added to existing forms that already have their own nonces, and the one you've added just clashes with them. (If you were adding a new form you would need these, yes.)

So I think the fix is to remove

```
<?php wp_nonce_field( '_themename_user_extra_fields_verify' ); ?>
```

and

```
check_admin_referer( '_themename_user_extra_fields_verify' );
```

and the forms will still be secure. I don't think you need the user edit permissions check either.

---

That all said, you could implement Facebook and Twitter as extra contact info fields instead:

```
function wpse_376873_add_contactmethods( $contactmethods ) {
    $contactmethods['facebook'] = __( "Facebook Profile Link", "_themename" );
    $contactmethods['twitter'] = __( "Twitter Profile Link","_themename" );

    return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'wpse_376873_add_contactmethods', 10, 1 );
```

and most of this should just work automatically without having to write HTML for the fields. I don't think you can set extra field descriptions though as you have for your own fields.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I hadn't noticed this was Facebook and Twitter. I've seen those done as contact fields instead, so I've added a snippet for that, but I don't know if the values will end up escaped in the same way though.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information, appreciate it but i can't risk my theme getting a soft rejection because of this being wrongly escaped. still thank u for the information now i know it could be done this way too :)